# Add Windows User to local SQL Server with PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, powershell

I would like to add an existing local user to the SQL Server as a sysadmin, with PowerShell. fter some research I have the following script so far:

```
$Username = "JohnDoe"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 
$SqlServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "localhost"
$SqlUser = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $SqlServer, "$Username"
$SqlUser.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'
$SqlUser.Create()
$SqlUser.AddToRole('sysadmin')
```

The user exists on localhost, it is member of the Users and the Administrators group. I got the following error message:

> Exception calling "Create" with "0" argument(s): "Create failed for
>   Login 'JohnDoe'. " At C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Desktop\try.ps1:7 char:16
>   + $SqlUser.Create <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> Exception calling "AddToRole" with "1" argument(s): "Add to role
>   failed for Login 'JohnDoe'. " At C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Desktop\try.ps1:8
>   char:23
>   +     $SqlUser.AddToRole <<<< ('sysadmin')
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2
What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

**EDIT:** Updated the script based on the suggessions from C.B. and mortb, but still not working. I have updated the script above to the current state, and the error message with that one what I am getting now.

Comment: Try and remove the '' around  `'$Username'` and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks, updated the script, but still not working. I have edited the question with the current script and the current error message.

Comment: I guess you need to disable password policy, if you have. I posted my answer. Check that.

Comment: No, not the password password policy, but the way the username is given. Username is only accepted in `"${env:ComputerName}\Username"` format. `"localhost\Username"` or `"Username"` is not accepted. I figured it out from your answer, many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not try your code. But, the following one worked for me on my SQL Express instance.

```
    $conn = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection -ArgumentList $env:ComputerName
$conn.applicationName = "PowerShell SMO"
$conn.ServerInstance = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
$conn.StatementTimeout = 0
$conn.Connect()
$smo = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $conn
$SqlUser = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $smo,"${env:ComputerName}\JohnDoe"
$SqlUser.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'
$sqlUser.PasswordPolicyEnforced = $false
$SqlUser.Create()
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out the problem was that the username is only accepted in `"${env:ComputerName}\Username"` format. `"localhost\Username"` or `"Username"` is not accepted.

Comment: You'll need to use `"$($smo.ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS)\Username"` if you are not running the PowerShell on the same machine as SQL Server, but are connecting to a remote server

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
'$Username'
```

with

```
"$Username"
```

Note that in powershell variable aren't expanded in single quote, then '$Username' is take as literal and not for the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, updated the script, but still not working. I have edited the question with the current script and the current error message.

Comment: try adding he server name in front ex: `mysqlserver\JohnDoe`

Comment: Just realized that basically your comment was right, it doesn't accept `localhost` but needs the hostname. Thank you.

Comment: No. My code works well as it is, the only thing I had to change is the format of the username.

Answer (score 1):

```
function SQL-Get-Server-Instance
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $DatabaseServer,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $InstanceName
    )

    if (!$InstanceName -or $InstanceName -eq "" -or $InstanceName -eq "MSSQLSERVER")
        { return $DatabaseServer }
    else
        { return "$DatabaseServer\$InstanceName" }
}


function Create-SQL-Login
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $loginName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $DatabaseServer,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
    )

    $sqlConnection = $null

    try
    {
        $Error.Clear()

        $ServerInstance = SQL-Get-Server-Instance $DatabaseServer $InstanceName
        $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerInstance;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;"

        $Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $Command.CommandType = 1
        $Command.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $Command.CommandText = "create login [$loginName] from windows with default_database=[master], default_language=[us_english]"
        $sqlConnection.Open()
        $Command.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
        $Command.CommandText = "exec master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'$loginName', @rolename = N'sysadmin'"
        $Command.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
    }

    catch
    {
        $str = (([string] $Error).Split(':'))[1]
        Write-Error ($str.Replace('"', ''))
    }

    finally
    {
        if ($sqlConnection)
            { $sqlConnection.Close() }
    }
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
Create-SQL-Login $env:COMPUTERNAME\JohnDoe $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: Many thanks for the effort, but it doesn't really show where is the error on my script. ravikanth's answer helped me to spot the problem though.

Comment: This function will work with more modern versions of SQL Server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found something simpler

`Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance <Server> -LoginName <User> -LoginType <LoginType> -DefaultDatabase tempdb -Enable -GrantConnectSql -LoginPSCredential $Credential

((New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "<Server>").Roles | where {$_.Name -eq 'sysadmin'}).AddMember("<User>")`