# Create a SQL login for Windows user

Tags: sql-server, powershell-3.0

```psh
$Username = "test-usr"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

$SqlServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "servername"
$SqlUser = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $SqlServer, "$Username"
$SqlUser.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'

$SqlUser.Create()
```

Getting Exception as follows:

```
Exception calling "Create" with "0" argument(s): "Create failed for Login 'test-usr'. "
At line:7 char:1
+ $SqlUser.Create()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

Does it require any special permission or any DLL to load?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610379/add-windows-user-to-local-sql-server-with-powershell   Maybe you're having the same issue because you aren't specifying machine name in your username?

Answer (score 1):

```
trap
{
    Write-Host("Line{0}:{1}: {2} `nInner: {3}" -f
        $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber,
        $_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine,
        $_.Exception.Message,
        $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message
        );   
}

try
{
$Username = "test-usr"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 
$SqlServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "servername"
$SqlUser = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $SqlServer, "$Username"
$SqlUser.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'

$SqlUser.Create()
}
catch
{
    throw $error[0];
}
```

Add some "Try/Catch" to see the real exception. Which is 'LoginType' is a ReadOnly property, I believe. 
I am still trying to figure out how to add DB User with login type "WindowsUser"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$error[0]|format-list -force` command that will take you at the details error StackTrace which will help you to analyze your detail error

For me, its showing database already exists and I physically delete that database from the location and re-run the script then its working fine