# Exception when trying to create a new SQL account

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I always get this error when i try to add a new login into my SQL server. 
I searched it online and I found this on StackOverflow
[Add Windows User to local SQL Server with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610379/add-windows-user-to-local-sql-server-with-powershell) but this didn't solve it.

This is the error

```
Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "Create failed for Login 'bilal'. "
```

This is my code

```
$server="WIN-SH7H3HP7KMI\SQL2014"
$User="bilal"
$password="test"

if(!($svr.Logins.Contains($User)))
{

    $login = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $server, $User
    $login.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin
    $login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
    $login.Create($password)
    Write-Host("Login $loginName created successfully.")
}
```

Comment: Does the SQL Instance have more details as to why it failed? Perhaps there are password restrictions in place. Do you have rights to create these accounts as well?

Comment: no thats the only error i get

Comment: You are sure that user was not already create from a migration task or testing? http://www.beansoftware.com/T-SQL-FAQ/create-failed-for-user.aspx. Your if statement could still evaluate to null triggering the clause. Since we don't see `$svr` declared I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Matt i put my entire script below

Answer (score 1):

@Matt this is the hole script
because it's giving me more error's who are lookalike the error i displayed in my question i was just focussing on that errror

```
$server="WIN-SH7H3HP7KMI\SQL2014"
$Database="master"
$User="bilal"
$Role="db_owner"

$Svr = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $server

# create new database and add to server
#     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')
#$srv=new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server('(local)\Test')
#$db=New-Object  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv,'Test_SMO_Database')
#$db.Create()

#Check Database Name entered correctly
$db = $svr.Databases[$Database]
if($db -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host " $Database is not a valid database on $Server"
    Write-Host " Databases on $Server are :"
    $svr.Databases|select name
    break
    }
 #Check Role exists on Database
    $Rol = $db.Roles[$Role]
if($Rol -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host " $Role is not a valid Role on $Database on $Server  "
    Write-Host " Roles on $Database are:"
    $db.roles|select name
    break
    }
if(!($svr.Logins.Contains($User)))
    {
    $password="test"
    $login = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $server, $User
    $login.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin
    $login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
    $login.Create($password)
    Write-Host("Login $loginName created successfully.")


    }
if (!($db.Users.Contains($User)))
    {
    # Add user to database

    $usr = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User') ($db, $User)
    $usr.Login = $User
    $usr.Create()

    #Add User to the Role
    $Rol = $db.Roles[$Role]
    $Rol.AddMember($User)
    Write-Host "$User was not a login on $Database on $server"
    Write-Host "$User added to $Database on $Server and $Role Role"
    }
    else
    {
     #Add User to the Role
    $Rol = $db.Roles[$Role]
    $Rol.AddMember($User)
    Write-Host "$User added to $Role Role in $Database on $Server "
    }
```